# Issue with cloning git repository

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to clone the git repository and i am getting error

```
Unable to negotiate with <server>: no matching key exchange method found.
Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I edited  `~/.ssh/config` and added

```
Host somehost.example.org
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"
```

but still I am getting same error.

Other solution is to use the command `ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` but I am getting connection refused with port no 22 as well.

I am using windows machine.

Comment: did you follow all the steps in https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/ I belive you have missed out one or two things from it and that led to this issue.

Comment: Can you share the command you used?

Comment: In the `.ssh/config/` you did not surround the entry in double quotes (`"`), right?

Comment: If you have the ssh-agent running in the background, you have to restart it after editing `~/.ssh/config` (search for `ssh-agent.exe` in the Task Manager). This worked for me after upgrading Git for Windows to v2.25.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is described in details [here](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html):

> If the client and server are unable to agree on a mutual set of parameters then the connection will fail.
>   OpenSSH (7.0 and greater) will produce an error message like this:
>   `Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1: no matching key exchange method found.
>   Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

---

#### Setting alternate ssh keys

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C <your comment>
```

now add the public key under your server account and try again.

Answer (score 30):

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
```

attach my ssh config for people who come across the same issue

```
## use kex algorithm ##
Host 10.172.4.66
    KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

## Avoid Write failed : boken pipe issue ##
ServerAliveInterval 120
TCPKeepAlive no
```

use larger postBuffer if come accross another issue

> ```
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> fatal: early EOF
> fatal: index-pack failed
> ```

```
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 10000000000000000000000000000000

$ git clone ssh://xxx xx
Cloning into 'xx'...
remote: Counting objects: 105491, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32876/32876), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (105491/105491), 1.74 GiB | 19.55 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 105491 (delta 67211), reused 104583 (delta 66603)
Resolving deltas: 100% (67211/67211), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (16545/16545), done.
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I am still getting the exactly same error.

Comment: Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1? please edit my answer add your exceptions if you found why it not work.

Comment: Now I get `bad numeric config value '10000000000000000000000000000000' for 'http.postbuffer': out of range`.

Answer (score 22):

Appending the file ***C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config*** with below content worked for me:

`KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1`

Answer (score 15):

I am using windows, for my case git clone fails in Jenkins (running under system user).

Adding

```
Host somehost.example.org
   KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

into **~/.ssh/config** will make the clone running as the current user works.

For **other users**, the OpenSSH won't pick up the config. I have to add the above config into the global config file:  **"C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config"** to make it work.

This happens after I updated the git-for-windows client, new git disable some old key exchange method. Another work around is install older version of git. eg:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.20.1.windows.1

Comment: This was the thing that the other ones didn't have: `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config`

Comment: Thanks this worked out for me. greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

```
Host     xxxx.yyyy.com 
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Port     portNumber
User     userName-yourDomain-com
```

Include above lines in .config file and add .config file in .ssh directory where id_rsa.pub and other files are located.

Comment: I just upgraded git and I added `KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` in my config file, This worked for me, but why? I didn't need it before.

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when the client and server are unable to agree on the key exchange algorithm to use.

You can see in the error log what key exchange algorithms the server is offering to use. In case when your client is unable to work with the methods offered by the server, the error is thrown.

To fix this issue changes can be made on the client or server side. If you can change the server's configuration, that would be the better path to take as you wouldn't have to make changes in all clients.
To fix the issue on the server side, you need to upgrade/configure the server to not use deprecated algorithms.

If change on the server side is not possible, one could simply force the client to re-enable the key exchange algorithms the server is ready to work with. You can do this permanelty by updating the **~/.ssh/config** file on *linux* or **C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config** file on *windows* and adding the following lines :

```
Host example.org # you can use the * wildcard character. e.g. *.example.org or simplly * for all hosts
User yourUserName # optional
KeyAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 # you can also specify multiple algorithms by separating them with comma e.g. diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: Seems it should be `KexAlgorithms` not `KeyAlgorithms`. at least this worked for me on windows 10!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Git Changes from VS 2019 and having the same issue, you can resolve the issue from the client to re-enable the key exchange algorithms. You can do this permanently by updating the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\ssh** file on windows and adding the following lines :

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows and this error is happening in tortoise Git or Sourcetree try to generate your keys with puttYGen. Or create a new key from your existing private key with puttYGen (use the Load option) then save that private key with the extension ppk in a any folder.
After that, add this  key (with the extension ppk) in pageant (google to know how is the icon, it must appear in the right bottom corner next to hour) right click and add key.
Try to be sure you setup your tortoise or your sourcetree to use this ppk key.
Tortoise: Setting - Network - ssh client (must be TortoiseGitPLink.exe, if not is in the git tortoise git_home\bin folder)
Source Tree:  Tools - Options - SSh client Putty/PLink

Answer (score 0):

The error can also occur if somehow your generated key is not readable.

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), the codepath to sign learned to report errors when it fails to read from "ssh-keygen".

You will now have a clear error message:

```
failed reading ssh signing data buffer from...
```

(*before* getting to the point where "`Unable to negotiate with ...`")

See [commit 36fb0d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36fb0d07d83df475bc6b716795b2111f8408cbcf) (04 Oct 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 644195e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/644195e02f445bf4fcf79e47c339f593c7646c9e), 11 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`ssh signing`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36fb0d07d83df475bc6b716795b2111f8408cbcf): return an error when signature cannot be read
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> If the signature file cannot be read we print an error message but do not return an error to the caller.
> In practice it seems unlikely that the file would be unreadable if the call to ssh-keygen succeeds.
>
> The `unlink_or_warn()` call is moved to the end of the function so that we always try and remove the signature file.
> This isn't strictly necessary at the moment but it protects us against any extra code being added between trying to read the signature file and the cleanup at the end of the function in the future.
> `unlink_or_warn()` only prints a warning if it exists and cannot be removed.